# Deleting a Windows Azure Table from Table Storage - Cost?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

We currently have an Azure Table filled with logs. We have no idea how many records are in them but we know that we did +- 3 mil transactions. So in worst-case scenario we will have 300 mil. rows.

We want to completely delete all the logs. 
If we delete the table, will this mean 1 transaction or will this mean he will batch delete all the rows he can and getting around 3 mil. transactions again?

I can't find any official info about the fact that Delete table command is actually 1 transaction.

Any help?

Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Transactions are billed as single REST requests.

As such you will be charged for 1 transaction to delete the table.

Answer (score 0):

To be completely nosy that would (could) be two storage transactions:

- One to drop the table.
- One to re-create the table for continued logging.